Discord bot crashes immediately after sending a dm to anyone
When I try to send a dm with my discord bot through discord.js, it successfully sends the message in dms and replies to my message that it had sent the dm, but then crashes in terminal, I have tried multiple things to fix it, but all doesn't seem to work. I have tried to search on google to see if others experience the same, but no one else does, it looks like I'm the only one.
I tried  a lot of different methods to fix it, doesn't seem to work.
My code:

module.exports = {
    name: "dm",
    description: "DMs a user a message",
    async execute(message, args, Discord){

        const user = message.mentions.members.first();
        const msg = args.slice(1).join(" ");

        if (!user) return message.channel.send('you must ping whoever you want to send the dm to');
        if (!msg) return message.channel.send("no message was written to send");

        try {
            if(message.member.roles.cache.has('1267019315337760810')){
                if(user){
                    const memberTargter = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
                    memberTargter.send(msg);
                    message.channel.send('sent');
                }
            } else{
                message.channel.send('you dont have permission to do that')
            }
        } catch (error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}

What was supposed to happen is that it would send the DM flawlessly, but what actually happened is this crash error:
Full terminal error:
node:events:497
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\EL HAMD\Desktop\fire-department-bot\index.js:51:55)
    at Client.emit (node:events:531:35)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\EL HAMD\Desktop\fire-department-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:28:14)
    at module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\EL HAMD\Desktop\fire-department-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\EL HAMD\Desktop\fire-department-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:355:31)    
    at WebSocketManager.<anonymous> (C:\Users\EL HAMD\Desktop\fire-department-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:239:12)     
    at WebSocketManager.emit (C:\Users\EL HAMD\Desktop\fire-department-bot\node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.cjs:287:31)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (C:\Users\EL HAMD\Desktop\fire-department-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:1190:51)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (C:\Users\EL HAMD\Desktop\fire-department-bot\node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.cjs:287:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\EL HAMD\Desktop\fire-department-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:1005:14)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:402:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)

Node.js v20.16.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...


Please show the code at and around the line at which the error occurs (C:\Users\EL HAMD\Desktop\fire-department-bot\index.js line 51). The code you posted has only line accessing a property id but that can't be the cause because it's user.id within if(user).

My code in index.js is: (The 51 is the line)
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
51    let prefix = await db.get(prefix_${message.guild.id})
if (prefix == null) prefix = ':';
if (message.content == '<@1268508879893958676>') {
    message.reply(`My prefix is "**${prefix}**"`)
}

})

So message.guild is null at that point but you don't check for that, that's your issue. (But please edit the index.js code into your question, right now it's horrible to read, comments are not meant for that.)

From what I can puzzle together in the code you shared, the issue is that your code crashes accessing message.guild.id in messageCreate because message.guild is null.
Now, message.guild will not be set if the message does not belong to a server, i.e. it's a DM. My assumption is that the DM you get notified about (and crash on) is the one you yourself just sent!
The solution is therefore to check whether the incoming message even has a guild before trying to access it. Just add if (!message.guild) return at the beginning of your messageCreate handler.

Thank you so much for your answer, I tried it and it worked. I can't tell you how much I'm happy because I have been trying to find an answer or a solution to this problem for a long, long time, and now I'm finally reliefed.
